# Merge-sort implementation doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort in C using arrays, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int s[], int low, int middle, int high)
{
    int i,l=0,r=0;
    int left[high/2], right[high/2];

    for(i = low; i<=middle; i++) left[i-low] = s[i];
    for(i = middle+1; i<=high; i++) right[i-middle-1] = s[i];

    i = low;
    while(l <= middle-low || r <= high - middle - 1)
    {
        if(left[l] <= right[r])
        {
            s[i++] = left[l];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            s[i++] = right[r];
            r++;
        }
    }
    while(l <= middle-low)
    {
        s[i++] = left[l];
        l++;
    }
    while(r <= high - middle - 1)
    {
        s[i++] = left[r];
        r++;
    }
}

void mergesort(int s[], int low, int high)
{
    int i;
    int middle;
    if(low < high){
        middle = (low + high)/2;
        mergesort(s, low, middle);
        mergesort(s, middle+1, high);
        merge(s, low, middle, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[] = {5, 345, 1, 120, 40, 3450};
    int size = (sizeof(nums))/(sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    printf("\n");
    mergesort(nums, 0, size);
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

That outputs:

```
5 345 1 120 40 3450 
0 1 4 5 40 120
```

Which is kind of close. Could someone point out my mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: Your merge function has suspicious upper bounds for the `for` loops, `<=` is most certainly wrong.

Comment: At first glance: Your upper array bounds are exclusive, as is usual in C. Which means all the `<=` as loop conditions should probably just be `<`. Your right subarray will also be one element short when `high` is odd.

Comment: Changing all the <= into < breaks the code. Now it prints what seem to be random pointer values and there's also a segmentation fault, which I can't trace with gdb.

Comment: And this is why you really *should* use pointer-arithmetic in c. You could express this *much* clearer by passing the start of the sub-array to be sorted to `mergesort()` each time, rather than fudging the offsets. Also, allocating the temporary arrays on the stack doesn't scale to larger sets to be sorted.

Comment: The comments don't say that your code will work when you change the condition. They ask you to look further into these conditions and to check your code. These changes don't break the code either; the code is already broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the array out of bounds at several places. Your code uses C-style ranges, which have an inclusive lower bound `L` and an exclusive upper bound `H`. Exclusive means that the upper bound `H` is not a valid index in the (sub-)array. A typical loop over the range look like this:

```
for (i = L; i < U; i++) ...
```

or

```
i = L;
while (i < U) ...
```

A greater-than-or-equal operator `<=` in such loops should make you wary, as should suprious additions or subtraction of 1. They might be correct in some cases, but they are usually consequences of inconsitent array indexing.

Let's revise your code with the C-style ranges in mind:

```
int left[high/2], right[high/2];
```

The array sizes are wrong. The left array has `middle - low` elements and the right array has `high - middle` elements. If the array size `high - low` is odd, you have one more element in right than in left.

```
for(i = low; i<=middle; i++) left[i-low] = s[i];
```

You mistakenly put the middle element in the left array. It is the first element of the right array.

```
for(i = middle+1; i<=high; i++) right[i-middle-1] = s[i];
```

Same here, plus you access `s[high]` which is one beyond the array.

```
i = low;
while(l <= middle-low || r <= high - middle - 1)
```

The conditions should have `<` and no `-1`. More importantly, the conditions should both be true, otherwise you access the subarrays out of bounds; hence the operator should be ´&&`.

```
    if(left[l] <= right[r])
```

The `<=` is okay, though, for once.

```
while(l <= middle-low)
{
    s[i++] = left[l];
    l++;
}
while(r <= high - middle - 1)
{
    s[i++] = left[r];
    r++;
}
```

Here, it should be `<` again. Also note that you access `left` with the index `r`, which is probably just a typo owed to copy and paste.

```
if(low < high){
    middle = (low + high)/2;
    mergesort(s, low, middle);
    mergesort(s, middle+1, high);
    merge(s, low, middle, high);
}
```

Here, the second call to megesort should be to `middle`, not to `middle + 1`. Because the upper bound is exclusive and the lower is not, adjacent arrays share the same bounds.

Here's a sort that works:

```
void merge(int s[], int low, int middle, int high)
{
    int i, l = 0, r = 0;
    int left[middle - low];
    int right[high - middle];

    for (i = low; i < middle; i++) left[i - low] = s[i];
    for (i = middle; i < high; i++) right[i - middle] = s[i];

    i = low;
    while (low + l < middle && middle + r < high) {
        if (left[l] < right[r]) {
            s[i++] = left[l];
            l++;
        } else {
            s[i++] = right[r];
            r++;
        }
    }

    while (low + l < middle) {
        s[i++] = left[l];
        l++;
    }

    while (middle + r < high) {
        s[i++] = right[r];
        r++;
    }
}

void mergesort(int s[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle;

    if (low + 1 < high) {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(s, low, middle);
        mergesort(s, middle, high);
        merge(s, low, middle, high);
    }
}
```

The code can still be improved. The different indices for the left and right subarrays make it difficult to maintain and test the code. If you have already learned about pointer arithmetic, you can do without the `low` bound entirely by passing `array + low` and the size as new array base, as EOF has suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

M Oehm provided an explanation and a fixed example of the original code in his answer.

Here is an alternate version that does a one time allocation of the temporary array and uses a pair of co-recursive functions to avoid copying of data. I'm  not sure why top down merge sort is used so often, bottom up merge sort is non-recursive, a little bit faster, and simpler to understand.

On my system, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz, this example can sort 20 million 32 bit integers in about 2 seconds. (A bottom up merge sort would take about 1.9 seconds).

```
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
void MergeRuns(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee);

void TopDownMergeSort(int a[], size_t n)
{
    int *b;
    if(n < 2)                           // if size < 2 return
        return;
    b = malloc(n * sizeof(int));        // one time allocation
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    free(b);
    return;
}

void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
size_t rr;
    if((ee - ll) == 1)                  // if size == 1 return
        return;
    rr = (ll + ee)>>1;                  // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
    MergeRuns(b, a, ll, rr, ee);        // merge b to a
}

void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
size_t rr;
    if((ee - ll) == 1){                 // if size == 1 copy a to b
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        return;
    }
    rr = (ll + ee)>>1;                  // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
    MergeRuns(a, b, ll, rr, ee);        // merge a to b
}

void MergeRuns(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                      // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                      // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                      // a[] right index
    while(1){                           // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)               //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                      //     and return
        } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                continue;               //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr)               //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                      //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time somebody declares a function argument as an array `foo(type bar[])`, a `sizeof()`-user dies.